# Unknown attribute Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and I am trying to get my application running.

My UserMigration.rb file contains:

```
class UserMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up

if (!ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? :users)
  drop_table :users

  create_table :users do |t|
    t.string :email
    t.string :first
    t.string :last
    t.string :password
    t.string :username
    t.integer :created_by

    t.string :bio #Newly added
    t.integer :id #Newly added
    t.string :photoURL #Newly added

  end
  add_index :users, :email
end
if (Models::Persistence::User.count == 0)
  Models::Persistence::User.create({:email => 'testuser@my.com',
                                    :username => 'testuser@my.com',
                                    :first => 'Test',
                                    :last => 'User',
                                    :password => 'Test123',
                                    :bio => "User, student",
                                    :id => "1",
                                    :photoURL => "http://link",
                                    :created_by => 1})
```

And my models User.rb file contains:

```
module Models
    module Persistence
      class User < ActiveRecord::Base
         validates :bio, :presence => true, length:  {minimum: 150}
```

I am working off an example and I just recently added the three extra fields in the users table (bio, id and photoURL). I keep getting this error when I run my tests with the newly added fields on the db:

```
      undefined method `bio' for #<Models::Persistence::User:0x007f8c04ae6838>
```

Any pointers on where I could start debugging this from? Thanks!

Comment: Have you migrated your test db? `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate` or `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: Yes, tried. No change. I am using Postgres with Rails. Right now, to get it working I am thinking of adding the column manually.

Comment: Create a separate migration for adding those attributes to the existing table. Then migrate to the database.

Comment: Perfect, just checked in in. Thank you, all!